# ReactiveUI 4.2.1 NuGet package

Tags: reactiveui

I'm trying to add the ReactiveUI NuGet package to a new VS2012 C# WPF .NET 4.5 project, but the NuGet package manager reports a problem "unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.NotBeta'". Are the dependencies in the ReactiveUI NuGet package wrong, or has the Microsoft.Bcl.Async.NotBeta package been removed? I can successfully install Rx-Main, which apparently does not depend on this Async.NotBeta package.

Here is the exact error from the package manager console:

```
PM> install-package reactiveui
Attempting to resolve dependency 'reactiveui-core (= 4.2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Main (= 2.0.21114)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Interfaces (= 2.0.21114)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Core (= 2.0.21114)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Linq (= 2.0.21114)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-PlatformServices (= 2.0.21114)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.NotBeta (= 1.0)'.
install-package : Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.NotBeta (= 1.0)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package reactiveui
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to version 4.2.2, it has been fixed, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/143)

Comment: When installing via nuget package via vs2012 to silverlight project it is throwing below error 
**Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Splat 1.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Comment: How would I get latest version of ReactiveUI_SL5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try this.
1- Close VS2012
2- Remove your local packages folder 
3- open VS2012
4- try to add the ReactiveUI to a specific project.

I moved my repository path to higher level share with the whole team.